# display values in polar plot (matlab)

Tags: matlab, polar-coordinates

I am a newbie in MATLAB and I have to display values in polar plot. My values are like this

```
values1 = [1.424; 1.425; 1.411; 1.555; 1.023; 1.534]; % 100 values...
values2 = [120.323; 112.414; 114.412; 120.333; 120.665; 121.888]; % 100 values...
```

I figured out how to draw a plain circle but I don't know how to affect the line with those values (and draw the other one).

```
t = 0 : 2*pi/100 : 2*pi; 
r = (power(sin(t),2) + power(cos(t),2));
polar(t,r)
```

I am expecting something like this (just found image for illustration). How can I do it? Thank you.
[image]

Comment: @excaza: I don't need to add text. I edited my post for better understanding.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. Do you just want to plot your data?

Comment: What is `polar(t, r)` with your actual data not doing that you're expecting?

Comment: Sorry, I am woring with MATLAB for the first time. My code draws only nice circle and I don't know how to insert the data (variables above) into the plot.

Comment: See: [`hold`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hold.html)

Comment: There are a number of tools on FileExchange which will draw a variety of polar plots for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this:

```
values1 = normrnd(100,10,1,101); % 101 values...
values2 = normrnd(100,10,1,101); % 101 values...
t = 0 : 2*pi/100 : 2*pi; 

figure,
polar(t,values1)
hold on
polar(t,values2)
hold off
```

For more information about the [`hold`](http://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hold.html) command check the Matlab help.